# Как сгруппировать массив байт по количеству дубликатов?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Например есть массив байт:

```
116, 101, 116, 104, 101, 116
```

Нужно отсортировать так чтобы получился массив:

```
116,101,104
```

ну или хотя бы:

```
116,116,116,101,101,104
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Выкинуть повторяющиеся элементы можно с помощью метода [`Stream.distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--):

```java
byte[] arr1 = {116, 101, 116, 104, 101, 116};

// преобразовываем в массив Byte[] и
// выкидываем повторяющиеся элементы
Byte[] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> arr1[i])
        .distinct()
        .toArray(Byte[]::new);

// если нужен именно массив byte[]
byte[] arr3 = new byte[arr2.length];

// заполняем массив byte[]
// значениями из массива Byte[]
IntStream.range(0, arr2.length).forEach(i -> arr3[i] = arr2[i]);

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [116, 101, 104]
```

Сгруппировать элементы можно с помощью метода [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```java
// если нужно посчитать количество дубликатов
Map<Byte, Long> duplicates = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> arr1[i])
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Byte::byteValue,
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.counting()));

// выводим результат
System.out.println(duplicates); // {116=3, 101=2, 104=1}
```

---

Сортировка по количеству дубликатов в данном случае не требуется, т. к. она повторяет порядок добавления элементов, но на всякий случай. Отсортировать элементы можно с помощью метода [`Stream.sorted(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
// сортировка по количеству дубликатов
Byte[] sorted = duplicates.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toArray(Byte[]::new);

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted)); // [116, 101, 104]
```

```java
// если нужно вывести все дубликаты
Byte[] sortedFull = duplicates.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .flatMap(e ->
                LongStream.range(0, e.getValue()).mapToObj(i -> e.getKey()))
        .toArray(Byte[]::new);

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedFull));// [116, 116, 116, 101, 101, 104]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Преобразуйте массив в List
2. List-ом инициализируйте LinkedHashSet
3. Создайте массив из LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 1):

Решение подразумевает, что порядок чисел в результате будет таким же, как в оригинальном массиве.

Если на входе у вас коллекция байт (то есть значение байта ограничено 0..255), то можно воспользоваться подсчетом, чтобы все операции заняли линейное время.

Пример

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{116, 101, 116, 104, 101, 116};

int[] counter = new int[256];

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    counter[bytes[i]]++;

byte[] result = new byte[bytes.length];

int pointerNew = 0;
int pointerOld = 0;
while (pointerOld < bytes.length) {
    int count = counter[bytes[pointerOld]];
    if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result[pointerNew] = bytes[pointerOld];
            pointerNew++;
        }
        counter[bytes[pointerOld]] = 0;
    }
    pointerOld++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

На выходе получаем

```
[116, 116, 116, 101, 101, 104]
```

Если вам на выходе нужны только уникальные значения, можно всего то поменять пару строк

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{116, 101, 116, 104, 101, 116};

int[] counter = new int[256];

int uniqueCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    if (counter[bytes[i]] == 0) uniqueCount++;
    counter[bytes[i]]++;
}

byte[] result = new byte[uniqueCount];

int pointerNew = 0;
int pointerOld = 0;
while (pointerOld < bytes.length) {
    int count = counter[bytes[pointerOld]];
    if (count > 0) {
        result[pointerNew] = bytes[pointerOld];
        counter[bytes[pointerOld]] = 0;
        pointerNew++;
    }
    pointerOld++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

На выходе получим

```
[116, 101, 104]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и с `BitSet` поиграться (но не забывая, что `byte` со знаком). Если не пользоваться растущим списком, а сразу создавать массив, то два прохода. Первый подсчитывает, второй генерирует:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] arr = { 116, 101, 116, 104, 101, 116, -7 };
        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
        for (byte rawByte : arr) {
            int value = rawByte & 0xff;
            bitSet.set(value);
        }
        byte[] result = new byte[bitSet.cardinality()];
        int index = 0;
        for (byte rawByte: arr) {
            int value = rawByte & 0xff;
            if (bitSet.get(value)) {
                result[index++] = rawByte;
                bitSet.clear(value);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> integerStream = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> (int) (o2.getValue() - o1.getValue()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[116, 101, 104]
```